# Casting a generic class. (cast) vs Class.cast()

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have searched for my use case and found some interesting answers but they are not as suitable as i need. What would the appropriate way to do this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T newInstance(String name) throws ClassCastException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return (T) loadClass(name).newInstance();
}
```

or a little different:

```
public <T> T newInstance(String name, Class<T> c) throws ClassCastException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return c.cast(loadClass(name).newInstance());
}
```

I think that both methods do the same. From my point of view method 1 is better because of less parameters. Boths throw a `ClassCastException` which will be fine for me. Truly, the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation is not nice.

Can someone tell me if there are any advantages for one method towards the other?

Edit: [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35860883/6032798) is correct. The following snippet can provide additional clarification.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new Object();
        // Exception at c.cast(o)
        Test.<String>realCast(o, String.class);
    }

    private static <T> T realCast(Object o, Class<T> c) {
        return c.cast(o);
    }
}
```

Using `realCast()` produces an Exception when `o` can't be cast to `c`. In comparison to that `fakeCast()` only gives a promise that the method's result is type of `T`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I think that both methods do the same.

No, they don't. Because at execution time, the first code doesn't know the type of `T` due to [*type erasure*](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ101). That means the cast basically does nothing within the method. The *calling* code might implicitly cast to whatever `T` it is specifying, but if the caller is another generic method (with the `T` used here as another type parameter), even that wouldn't want.

Here's a simple example of that:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new Object();
        // No exception
        Test.<String>fakeCast(o);
        // Exception at the point of assignment:
        // the code is effectively String x = (String) ...;
        String x = Test.<String>fakeCast(o);
    }

    private static <T> T fakeCast(Object o) {
        return (T) o;
    }
}
```

The second code knows the type of `T` in the form of `Class<T>`, so it *can* perform a real cast at execution time, at *exactly* the point you're performing it.

Comment: I think i understand it. fakeCast() casts on assignment not within method and realCast() casts in method before return.

Comment: @mr.b: No, `fakeCast()` itself doesn't cast *at all*. The cast within the method does absolutely nothing. It's just that when a method returns `T`, it actually just returns `Object` and the *calling* code does the cast if it actually uses the return value as `T`. Note how the first call doesn't result in an exception.

Comment: Yes, i have not well expressed what i mean. You are right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you look at the source code for Class.cast all it does is check if the object is the right type, and throws if not. The actual casting operation is identical. The difference is Class.cast will throw when *called*, while the cast operator will throw when the object is *used*.

Answer (score 3):

Well explained answer by Jon Skeet. I'd like to add an example here so that the differences can be observed clearly

### Class.cast()

```
public class Test{
      public static void main(String[] args){
            Object o = new Object();
            Test.castMethod(o, String.class); //Exception is thrown here
      }

      public static <T> T castMethod (Object o, Class<T> tClass){
             return tClass.cast(o)
      }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Object to java.lang.String
at java.base/java.lang.Class.cast
at com.test.Test.castMethod
```

Down-casting `Object.class` object to `String.class` is illegal here as they are not compatible.

By using `Class.cast()`,  **the casting does take place in `castMethod()` and hence throws `ClassCastException`.** That's what the **Real Casting** means as stated by Jon.

### Cast Operator

```
public class Test{
     public static void main(String[] args){
          Object o = new Object();
          Test.<String>castMethod(o); //No Exception
          String x = Test.<String>castMethod(o); //Exception is thrown here
     }
     public static <T> T castMethod(Object o){
          return (T) o;
     }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String
at com.test.Test.main
```

From the output, you can see that the `ClassCastException` is thrown at `main()`, unlike Class.cast() which throws exception at `castMethod()`. That's why Jon named it as **Fake Casting**, as the casting is actually done when the result of `castMethod` is assigned to the String variable. If the `castMethod` is called with the result being ignored, no exception will be seen at all.

Also, `return (T) o` will give you an ugly `Unchecked Cast` warning from the linter